# Cell size units in point to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have metadata in my .dat file that tells me that my cell size is 0.200 degrees longitude. I want to import this file into GIS and convert my points to raster.

My file is very simple: it has x, y coordinates and the variable. Its coordinate system is in NAD83.

I am wondering what value I  have to input for the cell size when I am using the point to raster toolset. I have two different files with two different resolutions (one is the 0.200 degress longitude and the other is 3km2); and so for cell size do I input 0.2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use 0.2 0r 3 depends on what you want to achieve. Instead of typing the numbers you could use the raster/files as the input and it will read the resolution from that. This is much easier and you are assured that the new raster has the same cell size as your input.

Comment: So just to clarify, the point data files (the .dat files I imported into GIS with the x y data and associated variable) automatically determines the resolution. I thought the default cell size is the shortest of the width or height of the extent of the input feature dataset, in the output spatial reference, divided by 250.

Comment: What determines the resolution while concerting to raster is another different raster that you will choose. Its from the second raster that the first raster will inherit its resolution from

Comment: What if I do not have another raster I can use. All I have are a series of point data files?

Comment: In that case you have to input a s[ecific value that is equivalent of the resolution you want